# Android back stack with multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, back, onbackpressed

I have a few activities and can't figure out a way to make it work with the backstack.

Is there a way to do this:

MainActivity ->(intent) subActivity ->(intent)subsubActivity->(back press)subActivity->*(back press)MainActivity

*This is where I am having problems. Since I am coming from my subsubActivity, even thought I used android:noHistory="true" in the manifest, it doesn't go back to main activity.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: call finish()  when you call intent from subactivity to subsubactivity

Comment: Why to use sub activities when you've fragments. It would be easy to handle backstack.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect candidate for using a combination of `startActivityForResult` and overriding `onActivityResult` in the calling `Activity`.

Assuming you have `Activity A`, which starts `Activity B` (which we cannot move back to), which starts `Activity C`:

`Activity A` will call `Activity B` the way you are now. `Activity B`, however, will call `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` instead of just `startActivity(Intent)`. This way, when we return from `Activity C`, we can call `finish()` on `Activity B` and return to `Activity A`, like so:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY_C = 1001; 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY_C) finish(); // If coming back from Activity C, finish()
    }

    private void openActivityC(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY_C);
    }

}
```

Now when you call `openActivityC()`, you're ensuring that `onActivityResult()` will be called when returning from `Activity C`, thus allowing you to end the `Activity` and return back to `Activity A`.

You can provide even more specific actions (such as setting/checking the result code (e.g. if it canceled (`Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`) or successful (`Activity.RESULT_OK`)) for statuses, to better determine what that calling `Activity` should do.

Hopefully that helps explain it a bit.

Edit: Also an afterthought, if there's no chance you'll ever want to go back to Activity B, then @Kay 's solution of just calling finish() after firing the Intent for Activity C would be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

If i get what you want You can use [startActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities(android.content.Intent[])) with an array of intents which will be fired one after another activity1->activity2->activity3 -back-activity2 -back-acitivty1